# Append html code to file using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, parsing

I have a Javascript function that takes a string and sends it via ajax to a PHP page. In PHP I would put this string inside the head tag (that already exist) of an html file. This change should be final. How could I do this? I don't know how to manipulate html code via PHP.

Comment: Metaprogramming (code that writes code) in PHP is scary and almost always a really bad idea. This is probably an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to accomplish by doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$htmlpage = file_get_contents('http://example.com/index.html');
echo str_replace("<head>", "<head>New text", $htmlpage);
//the result should be from <body></body> to <body>New Text</body>
?>
```

Also if you have text between `body` tags you can include it in

`str_replace("<body>Old Text", "<body>New Text", $htmlpage)`

If you have the string inside a varibale or you are using `$_POST` then instead of `"<head>New text"` put `"<head>".$_POST['thestring']`

Answer (score 0):

Just use if/else statements and echo string from ajax to your  tags if you can't use JS for this.

Comment: but how do I change the text inside the head tag with php? :\

Answer (score 0):

One way around this would be to use file_get_contents, then do a string replace on the  tag with the amended code, and then write the changes with the ammended code.

**Example**

```
<?php

$file = "myhtmlfile.html";
$original = file_get_contents($file);

$needle = "<head>";
$new_content = "<head>\n".$_POST['header'];


$replacement = str_replace($needle, $new_content, $original);

file_put_contents($replacement, $file);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks!! very helpful